# how do I implement ssim for loss function in keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I need SSIM as a loss function in my network, but my network has 2 outputs. I need to use SSIM for first output and `cross-entropy` for the next. The loss function is a combination of them. However, I need to have a higher SSIM and lower `cross-entropy`, so I think the combination of them isn't true.  Another problem is that I could not find an implementation of SSIM in keras.

Tensorflow has `tf.image.ssim`, but it accepts the image and I do not think I can use it in loss function, right? Could you please tell me what should I do? I am a beginner in keras and deep learning and I do not know how can I make SSIM as a custom loss function in keras.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-contrib/blob/master/keras_contrib/losses/dssim.py) for SSIM loss in Keras.
You can write a custom loss function and create SSIM loss for one prediction and cross-entropy for another. You can return a weighted sum of the two losses as the final loss.

Comment: this means I should use 1-SSIM if I want to minimize the loss function and I can not use SSIM with cross-entropy to minimize my loss function, right?

Comment: your job is to calculate the loss, your optimizer tries to minimize it. I am not sure what you are asking for.

Comment: I mean the better SSIM in image processing is higher and it should be near 1, but mse should be near zero to have a better algorithm. so I think if I use SSIM as loss function the optimizer should maximize it not minimize. so it means I should minimize 1 - SSIM, right?

Comment: You can use minimize `mse - ssim` (weighted suitably). So, when you minimize this quantity, `mse` is minimized and `ssim` is maximized.

Answer (score 0):

other choice would be
`ssim_loss = 1 - tf.reduce_mean(tf.image.ssim(target, output, max_val=self.max_val))`

then
`combine_loss = mae (or mse) + ssim_loss`
In this way, you are minimizing both of them.